# How to store Processor Status flags' values with corresponding enum for 6502

Tags: c++, cpu-registers, enum-flags, bitflags

I'm working on 6502 emulator in C++ as a part of my thesis.  It has 6 registers, most of them just hold values but there's one special - Processor Status. It's 8 bit wide and each bit means a different flag. The best choice for me seemed to make it std::bitset<8> and create a corresponding enum class to map its values to the real bits as follow:

```
enum class PSFlags : uint8_t
{
    Carry = 0,
    Zero = 1,
    InterruptDisable = 2,
    Decimal = 3,
    Break = 4,
    Unknown = 5,
    Overflow = 6,
    Negative = 7
};

struct Registers
{
    int8_t A;
    int8_t X;
    int8_t Y;
    uint8_t SP;
    uint16_t PC;
    static constexpr uint8_t PSSize = 8;
    std::bitset<PSSize> PS;

    constexpr Registers() noexcept :
        A(0),
        X(0),
        Y(0),
        SP(0xFF),
        PS(0b00100100),
        PC(0)
    {
    }
};
```

And now, if I want to refer to one of three: size of PS, the flag number or the bitset itself I have:

```
Registers::PSSize;  // size
PSFlags::Carry;     // flag number
Registers r; r.PS;   // bitset itself
```

Where every call accesses the value in a very different way. I'd like to have it more consistent, e.g.

```
Registers::PS::value;        // for the bitset itself
Registers::PS::size;         // for the size
Registers::PS::flags::Carry; // for the name of flag
```

Do you have any good ideas on how to achieve such (or similar) consistency without creating some crazy or ugly constructs in the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What OP wants (or something acceptable similar) can be achieved using nested `struct`s.

Just for fun, I tried to model what OP intended:

```cpp
#include <bitset>

struct Registers
{
    int8_t A;
    int8_t X;
    int8_t Y;
    uint8_t SP;
    static constexpr uint8_t PSSize = 8;

    struct PS: std::bitset<PSSize> {
      enum Flags {
        Carry = 0,
        Zero = 1,
        InterruptDisable = 2,
        Decimal = 3,
        Break = 4,
        Unknown = 5,
        Overflow = 6,
        Negative = 7
      };
      static constexpr unsigned Size = PSSize;

      constexpr PS(std::uint8_t value):
        std::bitset<PSSize>((unsigned long long)value)
      { }
      std::uint8_t value() const { return (std::uint8_t)to_ulong(); }
    } PS;

    uint16_t PC;

    constexpr Registers() noexcept :
        A(0),
        X(0),
        Y(0),
        SP(0xFF),
        PS(0x24),//PS(0b00100100),
        PC(0)
    {
    }
} r;
```

A small test to show this in action:

```cpp
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

#define DEBUG(...) std::cout << #__VA_ARGS__ << ";\n"; __VA_ARGS__ 

int main()
{
  std::cout << std::hex << std::setfill('0');
  DEBUG(std::cout << Registers::PS::Flags::Carry << '\n');
  DEBUG(std::cout << r.PS[Registers::PS::Flags::Carry] << '\n');
  DEBUG(std::cout << Registers::PS::Flags::InterruptDisable << '\n');
  DEBUG(std::cout << r.PS[Registers::PS::Flags::InterruptDisable] << '\n');
  DEBUG(std::cout << Registers::PS::Flags::Break << '\n');
  DEBUG(std::cout << r.PS[Registers::PS::Flags::Break] << '\n');
  DEBUG(std::cout << Registers::PS::Size << '\n');
  DEBUG(std::cout << "0x" << std::setw(2) << (unsigned)r.PS.value() << '\n');
  // done
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
std::cout << Registers::PS::Flags::Carry << '\n';
0
std::cout << r.PS[Registers::PS::Flags::Carry] << '\n';
0
std::cout << Registers::PS::Flags::InterruptDisable << '\n';
2
std::cout << r.PS[Registers::PS::Flags::InterruptDisable] << '\n';
1
std::cout << Registers::PS::Flags::Break << '\n';
4
std::cout << r.PS[Registers::PS::Flags::Break] << '\n';
0
std::cout << Registers::PS::Size << '\n';
8
std::cout << "0x" << std::setw(2) << (unsigned)r.PS.value() << '\n';
0x24
```

**Note:**

About naming the nested struct `Registers::PS` and the member `Registers::PS` with same name is I was expecting to work. Though, usually I use uppercase start character for type identifiers and lowercase start characters for variables. Hence, I don't have this issue usually.

As being in doubt about this, I tested the `struct Registers` against various compilers (though I wouldn't count this as proof against the standard): [Compiler Explorer](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/SUXNI3)

Deriving from `std::`containers should be done with care (i.e. better not). Probably for performance reasons, none of the `std::`containers provides a `virtual` destructor with the respective consequences. In the above code, this shouldn't be a problem.

---

[6502](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6502) reminded me to the [Commodore 64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_64) where I made my first attempts on (although the C64 had the even more modern [6510](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MOS_Technology_6510) CPU). However, that's looong ago... ;-)

Comment: Thanks @Scheff, this solution looks pretty good and esthetic! And I agree, emulators can put a person into a nostalgic mood ;)